# iis7 urlrewriting (iis module) image problem

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

I'm using IIS7 url rewrite module.
Here is my blog link: http://www.kad1r.com/
After rewrite here is some images paths.
http://www.kad1r.com/article/157/ASP.Net/images/comment.gif
But some images are ok (like google image).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Again I fix my problem.
I did not use / before some images :(